# Using Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY in Java to find minimum value

Tags: java, double, min, minimum, infinity

Simple question: will the following code work for finding the minimum value in an array of doubles (assume at least one value exists):

```
double[] values = ...

double currentMin = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if(values[i] < currentMin) {
        currentMin = values[i];
    }
}

return currentMin;
```

The crux of the question is whether POSITIVE_INFINITY will behave as expected when compared to other (real) double values, as well as potential infinities themselves.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is safe to use Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY. From [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1)

> All values other than NaN are ordered, with negative infinity less
>   than all finite values, and positive infinity greater than all finite
>   values.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the minimum to the first element of the array (values[0) since you assume that at-least one value exists.  If there is only one element, it must be the minimum, and otherwise, it will be updated accordingly.

Comment: Obviously that would work, but the real application here is a two-dimensional array of values, any of which may be flagged for skipping.  There's no convenient "first element" to use in this case.